# Rollback does not work well with Go language transactional wrapper

Tags: postgresql, go

I have recently started learning Go.

I found the following Github implementation of a wrapper for database transaction processing and decided to try it out.

(source) https://github.com/oreilly-japan/practical-go-programming/blob/master/ch09/transaction/wrapper/main.go

I am using PostgreSQL as the database.

Initially, it contains the following data.

```
testdb=> select * from products;
 product_id | price
------------+-------
 0001       |   200
 0002       |   100
 0003       |   150
 0004       |   300
(4 rows)
```

After Process A succeeds, Process B is intentionally made to fail, and a rollback of transaction A is expected. However, when we run it, the rollback does not occur and we end up with the following

In truth, since B failed, the process A should be rolled back and there should be no change in the database value.

I have inserted Logs in places to confirm this, but I am not sure. Why is the rollback not executed?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
)

// transaction-wrapper-start
type txAdmin struct {
    *sql.DB
}

type Service struct {
    tx txAdmin
}

func (t *txAdmin) Transaction(ctx context.Context, f func(ctx context.Context) (err error)) error {
    log.Printf("transaction")
    tx, err := t.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer tx.Rollback()
    if err := f(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Printf("transaction err")
        return fmt.Errorf("transaction query failed: %w", err)
    }

    log.Printf("commit")
    return tx.Commit()
}

func (s *Service) UpdateProduct(ctx context.Context, productID string) error {
    updateFunc := func(ctx context.Context) error {
        log.Printf("first process")
        // Process A
        if _, err := s.tx.ExecContext(ctx, "UPDATE products SET price = 200 WHERE product_id = $1", productID); err != nil {
            log.Printf("first err")
            return err
        }
        log.Printf("second process")

        // Process B(They are intentionally failing.)
        if _, err := s.tx.ExecContext(ctx, "...", productID); err != nil {
            log.Printf("second err")
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }
    log.Printf("update")
    return s.tx.Transaction(ctx, updateFunc)
}

// transaction-wrapper-end
func main() {

    data, err := sql.Open("pgx", "host=localhost port=5432 user=testuser dbname=testdb password=password sslmode=disable")
    if nil != err {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    database := Service {tx: txAdmin{data}}

    ctx := context.Background()

    database.UpdateProduct(ctx, "0004")
}
```

output

```
2022/05/26 13:28:55 update     
2022/05/26 13:28:55 transaction
2022/05/26 13:28:55 first process
2022/05/26 13:28:55 second process
2022/05/26 13:28:55 second err
2022/05/26 13:28:55 transaction err
```

database changes(If the rollback works, the PRICE for id 0004 should remain 300.)

```
testdb=> select * from products;
 product_id | price
------------+-------
 0001       |   200
 0002       |   100
 0003       |   150
 0004       |   200
(4 rows)
```

Please tell me how I can use the wrapper to correctly process transactions.

=========
PS.
The following code without the wrapper worked properly.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
)

// transaction-defer-start
type Service struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func (s *Service) UpdateProduct(ctx context.Context, productID string) (err error) {
    tx, err := s.db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer tx.Rollback()

    if _, err = tx.ExecContext(ctx, "UPDATE products SET price = 200 WHERE product_id = $1", productID); err != nil {
        log.Println("update err")
        return err
    }

    if _, err = tx.ExecContext(ctx, "...", productID); err != nil {
        log.Println("update err")
        return err
    }

    return tx.Commit()
}

// transaction-defer-end
func main() {
    var database Service
    dbConn, err := sql.Open("pgx", "host=localhost port=5432 user=testuser dbname=testdb password=passs sslmode=disable")
    if nil != err {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    database.db = dbConn

    ctx := context.Background()

    database.UpdateProduct(ctx, "0004")
    
}
```

Comment: No, because it is returning from that function after printing the error. @dei, why do you think this random code off the internet *does* work? Unless there is some magic going on I don't see where the queries use the `tx` from `Transaction`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The code is based on O'Reilly's book, so I thought it was credible, but I implemented the main function part by myself, so I consider this area suspicious. I have added the code that worked without the wrapper.

Also, I don't understand English very well and I use translation software, so I may say strange things sometimes.

Comment: Your code is certainly the "normal" way to handle transactions. And if you were going to build a wrapper the obvious way would be to just pass the `tx` into a function that could then use it. Don't trust random code you find on the internet.

Comment: I guess I was too trusting of the code because it was in the O'Reilly book, and I'm only in my second week with Go, so I guess I'm still a little short on knowledge. I will try to think in the direction of the advice you gave me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Richard Huxton said, pass `tx` into a function `f`

here are the steps:

1. add one field on `struct txAdmin` to accommodate `*sql.Tx`, so `txAdmin` have `DB` and `Tx` fields
2. inside `Transaction` set `tx` to `*txAdmin.Tx`
3. inside `UpdateProduct` use `*Service.tx.Tx` for every query

so the final code looks like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
)

// transaction-wrapper-start
type txAdmin struct {
    *sql.DB
    *sql.Tx
}

type Service struct {
    tx txAdmin
}

func (t *txAdmin) Transaction(ctx context.Context, f func(ctx context.Context) (err error)) error {
    log.Printf("transaction")
    tx, err := t.DB.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // set tx to Tx
    t.Tx = tx

    defer tx.Rollback()
    if err := f(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Printf("transaction err")
        return fmt.Errorf("transaction query failed: %w", err)
    }

    log.Printf("commit")
    return tx.Commit()
}

func (s *Service) UpdateProduct(ctx context.Context, productID string) error {
    updateFunc := func(ctx context.Context) error {
        log.Printf("first process")
        // Process A
        if _, err := s.tx.Tx.ExecContext(ctx, "UPDATE products SET price = 200 WHERE product_id = $1", productID); err != nil {
            log.Printf("first err")
            return err
        }
        log.Printf("second process")

        // Process B(They are intentionally failing.)
        if _, err := s.tx.Tx.ExecContext(ctx, "...", productID); err != nil {
            log.Printf("second err")
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }
    log.Printf("update")
    return s.tx.Transaction(ctx, updateFunc)
}

// transaction-wrapper-end
func main() {
    data, err := sql.Open("pgx", "host=localhost port=5432 user=testuser dbname=testdb password=password sslmode=disable")
    if nil != err {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    database := Service{tx: txAdmin{DB: data}}

    ctx := context.Background()

    database.UpdateProduct(ctx, "0004")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The rollback worked properly with the code you taught me.

Thanks to Richard Huxton for the advice and Rahmat Fathoni for the detailed instructions on how to improve the code.

I will try my best to be a good engineer like you.